# How to transfer an input value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a menu builder like wordpress. I have something like this in the pic. ( https://prnt.sc/podhpu ). I enter a value in the left side then click button "Menü Ekle - eng. Add Menu" But value goes empty.

I tried to transfer the value into a variable called "x". Then on click i tried to send x in value"" but it is not working. I think it needs something like trigger before sending it but i do not know exactly.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="kt-portlet__body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>URL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control menu-url" value="" placeholder="Menü başlığını giriniz.">
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Başlık</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control menu-title" value="" placeholder="Menü bağlantı adresini giriniz.">
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="add-menu" class="btn btn-brand btn-elevate btn-icon-sm">Menü Ekle</a>
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
$(function(){
            var x = $('.menu-url').val();
            $('#add-menu').on('click', function (e) {
                $('#menu').append('<li>\n' +
                    '                    <div class="menu-item">\n' +
                    '                        <a href="#" class="delete-menu">\n' +
                    '                            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>\n' +
                    '                        </a>\n' +
                    '                        <input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Menü Adı">\n' +
                    '                        <input type="text" name="url[]" val="'+ x +'" placeholder="Menü Linki">\n' +
                    '                    </div>' +
                    '<div class="sub-menu"><ul></ul></div>\n' +
                    '                    <a href="#" class="add-submenu btn">Alt Menü Ekle</a>\n' +
                    '                </li>');
                e.preventDefault();
            });
```

I want to transfer entered value when i click to "add menu" button.

Answer (score 0):

value is true attribute not val.

and you forget a bracket too.

```js
$(function(){
  var x = $('.menu-url').val();
  $('#add-menu').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#menu').append(
        `<li>
          <div class="menu-item">
            <a href="#" class="delete-menu">
              <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            </a>
            <input type="text" 
              name="title[]" 
              placeholder="Menü Adı"> 
            <input type="text" 
              name="url[]" 
              value="${x}" 
              placeholder="Menü Linki">
          </div>' +
          <div class="sub-menu"><ul></ul></div>
          <a href="#" class="add-submenu btn">Alt Menü Ekle</a>              </li>`);
    e.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="menu-url" value="i am here"
  placeholder="menu url"> 
<button id="add-menu">add menu</button>
<div id="menu"></div>
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for your help. But you are missing a point. When the page is opened my value is empty. I will enter a value and then click the button and my value will be transferred. But for your example your value is already set as "i am here".

Comment: use `$(document).ready({ $('.menu-url').val('your value') })`

Comment: I added my HTML code also. So maybe you can figure out it better. I have ``` $(function(){ }); ``` in my codes. So it is supposed to be the same i think. I want to enter my value lively and then click the button...